# Getting results of location permission dialog

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, core-location

I am doing [this tutorial](http://www.vellios.com/2010/08/16/core-location-gps-tutorial/) that would return the GPS coordinates. When I run the application on the iPhone, I am first presented with the `UIAlertView` asking permission to access my GPS coordinates.

I need to know from where this `UIAlertView` is thrown? Is it from the OS?
Can we capture this method? When the user clicks on "Allow" or "Don't allow", can I print his choice to the console?

How can I do this programatically? Is there an event for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This alert is shown by the OS. The usage of location-based API must be permitted by the user. You can ask the `CLLocationManager` for the current `authorizationStatus` and be notified when the status changes (delegate method will be called). Note that the user also can disable location services later in the settings app.

Comment: Ok, for example say that the user clicks on `No` or do not allow permission to access the GPS location. but the user has changed his mind later and he requires to authorize permission to access GPS. In that case how do i call the `UIAlertview` again ?

Comment: @sharon - You don't. You didn't call it the first time. You can watch for changes in your authorization, so you can opt out of location functions if you want. But you can't ask the user for permission again. Of course, if you notice you don't have permission, you could always fire YOUR OWN alert about that. But they'd have to dig into their settings to turn on your permissions, you can't send them there directly.

Comment: As of iOS5, you can create your own "Settings" button and have it call: [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=General"]];  to enable direct access to the settings.

Comment: @paiego's suggestion - It seems like the iOS 8 way of doing it is: `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString]];
`

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using CLLocationManager. Your delegate will get locationManager:didChangeAuthorizationStatus when the applications ability to use the API changes.

Edit:
The first time your application attempts to use the service, the user will be prompted. If the user answers No, your application will not be able to use the service unless they go to Settings->General->Location Services and change the setting for your application.

If you query the API for status and are disallowed, you could put up your own pop-up and instruct the user on how to change the setting for your application.

Comment: Ok, for example say that the user clicks on `No` or do not allow permission to access the GPS location. but the user has changed his mind later and he requires to authorize permission to access GPS. In that case how do i call the `UIAlertview` again ?

Comment: I believe the user would have to go to the iPhone settings screen and change the selected option for your application.